# Unknown class MyOldClass in Interface Builder file

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I saw other posts about the error:

```
Unknown class MyOldClass in Interface Builder file.
```

It happened to me when i deleted "MyOldClass" and added a new class for the nib's file owner.  I also made sure 'MyOldClass' was not in the targets and my new class was.  I also tried going to Build->Clean All Targets.  I still get that error.  How does xcode still have reference to MyOldClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface Builder files are just XML, so if you're sure you checked every outlet and object in your file, you can always try using `grep` to see if there's a reference hanging around:

```
$ grep "MyOldClass" MyIBFile.xib
```

I'd be careful modifying the text of this file, though. Make sure you can revert your changes if necessary.

Comment: if it's in vc and xml, then edit away. i have done this before without issue. `ibtool` may also apply this change.